# Design a database object that has multiple values for all columns

Tags: database-design

The table model below is the design of the actual form that we will give to our patients to fill out to store the 
info they will provide at the time of their initial exam. I am being asked to design/model the database objects 
to store this information. I determined that basically the fields in the far left side of this image 
(like 'chief complaint', 'posterior etc) to be the attributes and will become columns in the table. The check 
boxes are the actual values for these tables. All columns can have multiple values (meaning for each column 
multiple check boxes can be checked).

I have basically thought out two approaches (please keep in mind that 
there are more columns then I have showed above, I only decided to show part of the whole table I am trying to 
design to just show an example):

1) Design one table that will have a column for each possible value for each attribute.

pros and cons (in my opinion):

- It will make selecting and saving data from this table for the screen we are designing easy and simple.
- The table will be a very wide table (with almost 200 columns in it)

Am I violating some very basic database design principles here by creating one large table that will cause issues   down the road if there are changes to the screen/template?

2)  Turn all check boxes to code tables (basically these will become entities of their own)

if I do that I will now have to create a correlated table for each attribute (posterior, anterior) and relate a row in main     table to multiple rows in each correlated table for each column.

This will result in multiple code tables and one correlated table for each column. (18 correlated tables so far)

If I follow this design then in order to show the full picture of initial exam I will have to select data from over 18  tables  involved here, and forget about updating them.

I am leaning towards the first solution because it is simple,

The second solution is complicated and also I believe I am violating the very basic principles of database 
design by turning columns/attributes (posterior, anterior etc) to entities by turning them into correlated 
tables whereas these are really attributes and should result in columns. I will have to join between 18 tables 
at the very least If I want to show the complete exam picture.

I hope I have pictured my dilemma here, I need to design this object properly and the above two approaches are 
the only one I can think off, I need help to make the decision and may be there is another side to all this that 
I am not even taking into consideration. I hope someone has done something like this before and I can discuss 
this with them.

Unfortunately I am not able to post an image of the screen that would have given a much better idea of what I am talking about in terms of what screen that will display this data will look like so for that reason I will now try to show a picture in words:

initial exam table (the main table)

```
attributes/columns              possible values
posterior                       class1   class11   crowded      rotated
anterior                        overbite  open bite    upper     lower
erosion                         spaced  abraded fractured  discolored
bleeding                        normal  light  moderate advanced
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to reinvent the wheel, what you need is the: ["Entity–attribute–value model"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, you want to build an attribute table to hold all the possible values for attributes.

You can design an attribute table like this.

```
Attribute
---------
Attribute
Value
```

The primary (clustering) key is (Attribute, Value).  You would do an SQL select on the Attribute, and all of the Value rows would be returned.

Your rows would look like this

```
 Attribute          Value
 ----------------   -----------------
 posterior          class1
 posterior          class11
 posterior          crowded
 posterior          rotated
 anterior           overbite
 ...
```

Comment: first off, I have seen people asking some very rudimentary questions in this forum, my question was well thought out and I was not just looking for someone to do my work, I presented two choices and I wanted some folks who have more experience then me to help me pick the one choice that is better, still someone voted down my question I do not know why???? and took away from my not so many points as it is. I wish they would have explained why they are voting my question down.

Comment: @JUR: I didn't down vote your question.  I edited your question.  I don't know why your question was down voted.  I do know your question was hard for me to understand.  If you have a problem with my answer, feel free to comment.

Comment: Now to comment on Gibert's answer. Yes you are right I will create an attribute table to store the values for all attributes and then join with this table to actually get the values for each attribute, but my question was more about if I should create one dennormalized table that has one column for each value for each attribute that is possible or create the attributes table and then create a correlated table for values for each column and if I do that I would be joining  over 18 tables to get the complete picture. Which approach should be taken and why?

Comment: @JUR: I don't understand why my one Attribute table is not a complete solution to your question.  I don't understand why you need any other tables for attributes.

Comment: I tried to paste the screen shot of the screen I am trying to design and that prompted the question I have posed: how to store the data in that screen shot, but unfortunately I was not allowed to paste the screen shot because I do not have enuf reputation points and that is why my question is causing a bit of confusion because without that screen shot I do not blame you if you r confused by my question or if u question why ur answer is not a complete solution.  I will try to edit my question and if I am able to paste the screen shot you will know what I mean.

Comment: @JUR: Put the screenshot on imgur, and I'll put it in your question.

Comment: Now I have pasted the screen shot:

Comment: Now let me explain what is going on here: fields in far left side of the screen shot (posterior, anterior etc.) are the actual attributes for this table (i determined) and all the checkboxes are the possible values. Each attribute can have multiple values (checkboxes) now because each attribute has a many-to-many relationship with the attribute I do not have any other choice but to create a correlated table to store multiple values for each attribute or have a table where each possible value (checkbox) is an actual column in the table. Which one should be used?